# How to Setup PyDev/Eclipse in Lion?

Tags: python, eclipse, osx-lion, pydev

I'm a little bit confused about how to approach this. I had never used OS X before and I don't know how to configure it. After downloading PyDev with Eclipse I go to "Preferences > PyDev > Interpeter - Python > Auto Config" as I would normally do. I select the packages:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A72Vj.png)

But then I keep getting this message:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laZ6u.png)

I've read somewhere that I should download Xcode to get GCC (which is over a GB), then download and build python with it,... and then start working. But doesn't sound like it makes a lot of sense since Lion already comes with python 2.7.x which is what I'll be using.

Any idea on how could I properly set this up? Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it may have Python installed, but PyDev wants to be able to view the source of the python files to enable autocompletion.

Install Xcode, yeah. Xcode ships with the developer version of Python, which includes all those .py files. I'm fairly sure that you don't actually need to build Python from scratch (I never had to) - just installing Xcode itself should be enough.

Comment: ok, ho capito. Thanks, I'll try that and close the thread or come back with update when I get Xcode downloaded

Comment: This may work, but it's like killing a fly with a cannon (just getting the python version from http://python.org is much easier)

Comment: It's just not the recommended way ;-)

Comment: Hi, I also have this problem on Lion. I already installed XCode, but nothing changes.. how can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, install python from http://python.org (there's a mac version download there) and use that version (and don't fiddle much with the version that's installed in mac itself as it's not suitable for development as it doesn't come up with sources and other programs may rely on it, so, if something bad happens and you break it, it won't affect your system).